# Z-index issue for Time.ly calendar plugin for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, calendar, popup, z-index

I'm trying to finish up a site but I can't seem to figure out why the popup summaries on the calendar go behind the subscribe buttons at the bottom of the calendar. I'm assuming it's a z-index issue but I can't figure out why none of the z-index css styles work.

The test url for the calendar page is http://powhatan.idtestsite.com/events. To see what I'm referring to go to the bottom of the calendar and hover over "Event 2". You'll see it goes behind the subscribe buttons.

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

What a mystery! You have position and z-index set on both elements...

Don't know how much it helps or hurts, but I did notice that the z-index behaves as expected in FF 14.  In Chrome, I'm seeing the same behavior you report. Maybe that can help you track it down.

**EDIT:**

I found a solution - set the btn z-index to less than 0 (I used -1) and it behaves as expected in Chrome. This has to do with the lowest z-indexed item being absolutely positioned and the highest being relatively positioned. Sometimes those absolutely positioned elements write on top of relatively positioned ones, even though the indexes are set correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually just figured out the solution a minute ago. I added `#ai1ec-calendar-view-container { 
  z-index: 1 !important; 
}` and it worked like a charm. Only took me three days to figure out :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to my CSS and elemented all other z-index styles that pertained to my calendar and it worked like a charm:

`#ai1ec-calendar-view-container { 
  z-index: 1 !important; 
}`